# ¿Es seguro utilizar la API Rest de Google Drive desde el navegador del cliente con javascript?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-drive

Tengo una aplicación web con base de datos en un VPS con Ubuntu. La idea es ahorrar con la transferencia de datos que cobran, colocando las imágenes del fichero de artículos en Google Drive, donde no cobran por la transferencia de datos. Sin embargo tendría que conectarme a la Api Drive desde el navegador del cliente con javascript, después de que el servidor sirva la página web (sin las imágenes), y después cargar las imágenes que faltan desde GDrive.

Ahora, he visto por encima la documentación de esta API y hay que conectarse mediante un proceso de autenticación (OAuth) donde habrá que suministrar un ID-Cliente y una clave, y no sería seguro incluirlo en el script de javascript del navegador. Tengo muchas dudas con todo esto y sobre todo por la seguridad. ¿Hay otra forma mejor de hacer esto?

Comment: puedes utilizar el modo offline, donde teniendo un json se lo insertas directamente al `client` y esto queda del lado de backend, esto depende del lenguaje que estés usando para el back, pero el usuario ya no tendría que hacer ninguna autenticación oauth, sería transparente para él.

Comment: Realmente para imágenes concretamente Google lo ha puesto complicado últimamente, antes, cuando existía Picasso, podías embeber una imagen en cualquier parte como tal (me refiero a un archivo con extensión `.jpg` o parecida). Ahora con Google es complicado. No sé si desde la API sea más fácil. En cuanto a la seguridad no debe haber problema, lo único es que desde el cliente la API KEY queda expuesta, pero, en la consola de proyectos puedes indicar que sólo se pueda usar esa API KEY desde tu dominio. Además, si das autorización de sólo lectura no creo que haya mayor riesgo...

Comment: ... Otra posibilidad sería usar `Flickr`. De hecho, yo lo uso en mi sitio y me permite embeber imágenes como tales, usando únicamente la URL de las mismas, no hay que recurrir a APIs ni a nada. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://www.deiverbum.org/jacob-el-hombre-que-lucho-con-dios/) donde la imagen está alojada en `Flickr`. La cuenta que tengo es gratuita, con un ¡1TB de almacenamiento!. Ellos tienen código de generación para incluir imágenes, pero lo puedes modificar a tu gusto, o  simplemente usar la URL de la imagen y darle los estilos que quieras.

Comment: Sr1871, no entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir, pero uso el framework Django y python.
A.Cedano, he encontrado este tutorial en la documentación para hacerlo con javascript, pero como tu dices queda expuesto todo el código:https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js
Aunque todavía no es seguro que tenga que conectarme a la GDrive, porque dependerá de dónde tenga la base de datos el proveedor, podría estar en DropBox, etc.Lo importante en este caso sería el proceso del flujo de datos en cuestión, lo ideal es que el servidor no tenga que servir los archivos pesados.